# не выполняется условие в while loop си

Tags: c, list, while, циклы

Мои переменные:

```
struct car
{
    char registration[7];
    char model[30];
    char colour[30];
    int num;
    bool reserved;
    long amount;
};
```

Следующим образом я собираю данные про машину:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        printf("**************Car %d:**************\n", i + 1);


    while (valid_input == 0) {
            printf("Enter registration number (format: yyDnnnn): \n");
            scanf("%s", aRegistration);
            int len = strlen(aRegistration);
            if (len == 7){
                if (((aRegistration[0] == '0' && aRegistration[1] >= '1' && aRegistration[1] <= '9') ||
                    (aRegistration[0] == '1' && aRegistration[1] >= '0' && aRegistration[1] <= '4')) && (aRegistration[2] == 'D')
                    && ((isdigit(aRegistration[3]) >0 ) && (isdigit(aRegistration[4]) > 0) && (isdigit(aRegistration[5])>0) &&
                        (isdigit(aRegistration[6]) >0)))
                            valid_input = 1;
                else  printf("\007Error: Do not match the format!\n");
        }
    }


        printf("Enter model: \n");
        scanf("%s", aModel);


        printf("Enter colour:\n");
        scanf("%s", aColour);
        do {
            printf("Enter number: \n");
            scanf("%d", &aNum);
        } while (aNum > 3);

        printf("Car is not reserved at this momemnt\n");
    aReserved = false;
    printf("Amount is 0, because car is unreserved.\n");
    anAmount = 0;
    }
```

Так же у меня есть два метода, которые помогают зарезервировать машину и наоборот отказаться от резервации. И они работают!

```
bool reserve(char* reg) {
    long anAmount;

    struct LinearNode *current, *previous;
    bool notFound = true;
    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no cars in the list\n");
    else {
        for (current = front; current != NULL; current = current->next)
        {

            if (strcmp(reg, current->element->registration) == 0) {

                if (current->element->reserved == false) {
                    printf("Write a deposit amount of your choice (more than 500 and less than 1500)\n");
                    scanf("%li", &anAmount);
                    if (anAmount >= 500 && anAmount <= 1500) {
                        current->element->amount = anAmount;
                        current->element->reserved = true;
                    }
                    printf("Now you are reserved this car!\n");
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Car is already reserved!\n");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("This car does not exist\n");
            }
        }//end for loop
    }
}

bool unreserve(char* reg) {
    int answer;

    struct LinearNode *current, *previous;

    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no cars in the list\n");
    else {
        for (current = front; current != NULL; current = current->next)
        {
            if (strcmp(reg, current->element->registration) == 0) {
                if (current->element->reserved == true) {

                    printf("Do you want to unreserve this car?\n");
                    printf("Press [1] if yes, and [0] if no.\n");
                    scanf("%d", &answer);
                    if (answer == 1) {
                        current->element->reserved = false;
                        current->element->amount = 0;
                //  return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Car remains reserved!");
                    //  return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //else {
                //printf("This car does not exist");

            //}
        }
    }
}
```

И теперь наступает момент, когда if statement не срабатывает.

Я пытаюсь продать машину. Но продать машину можно только ту, что зарезервирована. А в итоге продается любая машина, независимо от моего ограничения.

вот данный метод:

```
 void deleteCar(char* reg) {

struct LinearNode *current, *previous;
    bool found = false;

    if (isEmpty())
        printf("Error - there are no nodes in the list\n");
    else {
        current = previous = front;

        while (!found && current != NULL) {
            if ((strcmp(reg, current->element->registration) == 0) && (current->element->reserved = true)){

                found = true;

        } else {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }//end else
        } //end while

        if (!found)
            printf("Error - there is not such car with registration number %s\n", reg);
        else {
            if (current == front) {
                front = front->next;
                free(current);
            } //end else
            else {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);
            } //end else
            printf("Car with registration number %s has been deleted\n", reg);
        }//end else
    }//end else
}// end deleteNode
```

не выполняется следующее условие: 
    `current->element->reserved = true` в `while loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не читал целиком всю эту портянку, но бьюсь об заклад,что вместо

```
current->element->reserved = true
```

вам следует написать

```
current->element->reserved == true
```

а еще лучше просто

```
current->element->reserved
```

Comment: Вы правы! Спасибо большое!